# Server in gevent and other greenlets in the same app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, gevent, greenlets

I'm searching how to run server in gevent and other greenlets in one program. So I want to have server (multiple connections) and one or two other greenlets. Is this possible? If yes, then how?

Best regards, 
Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketServer, WebSocketApplication, Resource
import gevent

class EchoApplication(WebSocketApplication):
    def on_open(self):
        print ("Connection opened")

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.ws.send(message)

    def on_close(self, reason):
        print (reason)

def _test():
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(1)
        print ('other greenlet')

gevent.spawn(_test)

WebSocketServer(
('', 9007),
Resource({'/': EchoApplication})
).serve_forever()
```

this code is serving ws server and printing 'other greenlet' text :)